# Connecting Node.js app on Google Cloud App Engine to a Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Node app which uses MySQL, connecting via a config json:

```
{
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
        "host": "something",
        "user": "something",
        "password": "something",
        "database": "daimonion-db",
        "debug": false
    }
}
```

I've created a Google Cloud Platform SQL instance. I'm seeing an IP address and instance connection name.

I've also deployed the Node app to Google Cloud App Engine in a flexible environment.

How do I connect the Node app to the SQL instance? I'm seeing this explanation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine which tells me to add a settings string to my app.yaml to connect with either a Unix domain socket or TCP connection, but how do I connect to these from my Node app?

Answer (score 7):

include `beta_settings` to `app.yaml` to enable cloud proxy on the instance in production, and specify the UNIX socket `socketPath` in `config`, so your flex app can connect to the instance via proxy.

`socketPath` should be in `config` only if the app is running in production on App Engine. For local development, the TCP socket is used with the proxy client, that you need to install and start with the following commands:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy

chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306
```

here's an example of Node app that connects and queries a Cloud MySQL instance using the proxy. The `if` statement permits the app to switch configuration dev-local/prod-appengine automatically, [using environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) .

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
env_variables:
  SQL_USER: [SQL_USER]
  SQL_PASSWORD: [SQL_PASSWORD]
  SQL_DATABASE: [DATABASE_NAME]
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: [INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

var config = {
    user: process.env.SQL_USER,
    database: process.env.SQL_DATABASE,
    password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD
}

if (process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`;
  }

var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM entries', function(err, result, fields){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result);
        }
    );
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. On one of my projects, this works. On another, I get a connect etimeout error. I know that the database connection settings are valid and that the Cloud SQL instance is giving permission to the app service. What else should I check?

Comment: what is the configuration of this other project? does it have its own SQL instance or is the same one hosted in the other project?

Comment: is yaml file added to the source code or separately deployed as it contains the secret path it has to be ignored? How to handle the env variables

Comment: `const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host: config.host,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});`

and I get a `ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT`, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect `Cloud SQL` instance from local desktop:

Example for `postgresql`

1. Using public IP and `psql` tool: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip

   a. Add your external IP to `Cloud SQL` - `CONNECTIONS` - `Authorized networks`

   b. Modify your `connection.host` to `Cloud SQL` instance public IP
2. Using `cloud_sql_proxy` tool and `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy

Comment: How do I get an external IP for Google App Services?

Comment: @BorisK For GAE environment, not local desktop, take a look about https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql-postgres