# Connecting a Google Cloud App Engine app to its Cloud SQL Instance-allowing database access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud project with an app and a Cloud SQL Instance. SQL requests from the app time out. Private IP connectivity is enabled. If I explicitly add the app instances' IPs to the SQL Instance's public authorized networks, it works. This is obviously a bad solution since these IPs change on every deployment. How do I permanently grant access to the app?

Comment: Are you using Flexible or Standard environment? Did you try to follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine)?

Comment: I am using Flexible environment. I did follow the documentation, as well as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180722/connecting-node-js-app-on-google-cloud-app-engine-to-a-google-cloud-sql-instance/54330069#54330069 This worked for another, very similar project, but not for this.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance located in another project?

Comment: No, same project.

Comment: Mine is a stupid question but did you use the private ip in your configuration? If it works when you add your ip in the public authorized network, it must mean that you are using the public ip no?

Comment: My configuration is coming from the YAML. I haven't really configured anything about an IP

Comment: In the answer that you linked, there is this line `if (process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {`. Can you try to remove this condition, and in the `config` dictionary, directly add `socketPath:``/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}``; ` (there is an extra ` in this last line due formatting, you should remove it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private IP's are only accessible by other services on the same [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/). App Engine apps don't currently have access to VPC networks.

Edit: App Engine has recently released [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc), meaning that the can now be configured to connect via Private IP.

App Engine Standard does provide a unix domain socket to interface with Cloud SQL instances. Just tell your app to use the socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>;`  (with your instance's connection name), and it should be able to connect. If you are using a cross product or cross regional setup, there are more instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine).

Comment: Yet this Google documentation at https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/cloud-sql-now-supports-private-connections-and-app-engine-second-generation-runtimes says it is possible, but does not provide any examples (and i spent some afternoons trying to make the connection) I also tried to manually create a VPC peering, but you have to choose a source and destination VPC, yet Appengine VPC does not show up.

Comment: @AlexF That blog post was announcing 2 separate features - the first being Private IP support going GA, the second being support for the AppEngine runtimes.

However, a new feature (Serverless VPC Access) launched last week which will allow this (I've updated the original answer to reflect that).