# Node js is not connecting with Cloud sql via App Engine Google GCP

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud-deploy

I have deployed node js application into Google App Engine which has deployed successfully. I have also created db on cloud SQL and imported my local db there.
I am facing the error to  connect my node application with Cloud Sql DB, On local it is successfully connected with Cloud DB( I have added my local public IP in  Sql Connection public IP section).Most probably it is a handshaking issue between node.js and cloud sql.please help me on what approach I have to follow. I am sharing the code as well as the error which is mentioned below :

Code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({

    host: '34.131.200.46',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin@123',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'arcade',
  // socketPath:'/cloudsql/google.com:ethereal-honor-206415:us-central1:arcade'

});


dbConnection.connect(connect=>{

    console.log('connecttion =>>>>', connect)
}); 


exports.dbConnection = dbConnection;
```

Thanks & Regards
Shubham

Comment: I'd suggest to google a little a check the docs which explains how to connect GAE to Cloud SQL https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard.

Also there are tons of similar questions for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54330069/12265927.
The SO community expect you have done some effort investigating the issue before creating a question and then show that investigation here and why you've not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Unix sockets not the public IP of your Cloud SQL instance

> For public IP paths, App Engine standard environment provides encryption and connects using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy through Unix sockets.

Ref : https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#public-ip-default_1

Also make sure your service account has the appropriate Cloud SQL role and permissions.

More details here : https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#public-ip-default